# How do i create the functions of List<float> in the options file?

Tags: c#

I have in the options file two functions GetKey and SetKey.

I set a key then in the settings_file.txt it will look like:

`text = hello` where *text* is the key then = and *hello* is the value for the current key.

Now i need to add another two functions the first one is type of List that get a string and return a List

And a another function that get a Key and a List.

So this is the first two functions allready working GetKey and SetKey:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------
 * Module Name  : OptionsFile
 * Description  : Saves and retrievs application options
 * Author       : Danny
 * Date         : 10/02/2010
 * Revision     : 1.00
 * --------------------------------------------------------------*/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;


/*
 *  Introduction :
 * 
 *  This module helps in saving application options
 * 
 * 
 *  Typical file could look like this:
 *  user_color=Red
 *  time_left=30
 *  
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * */

namespace DannyGeneral
{
    class OptionsFile
    {
        /*----------------------------------------
         *   P R I V A T E     V A R I A B L E S 
         * ---------------------------------------*/


        /*---------------------------------
         *   P U B L I C   M E T H O D S 
         * -------------------------------*/
        string path_exe;
        string temp_settings_file;
        string temp_settings_dir;
        string Options_File;
        StreamWriter sw;
        StreamReader sr;

/*----------------------------------------------------------
 * Function     : OptionsFile
 * Description  : Constructor
 * Parameters   : file_name is the name of the file to use
 * Return       : none
 * --------------------------------------------------------*/
    public OptionsFile(string settings)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(settings))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(settings)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(settings));
            }
            File.Create(settings).Close();
        }
        path_exe = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
        Options_File = settings; 
    }

/*----------------------------------------------------------
 * Function     : GetKey
 * Description  : gets the value of the key.
 * Parameters   : key
 * Return       : value of the key if key exist, null if not exist
 * --------------------------------------------------------*/
    public string GetKey(string key)
    {

      //  string value_of_each_key;
        string key_of_each_line;
        string line;
        int index;
        string key_value;
        key_value = null;

        sr = new StreamReader(Options_File);
        while (null != (line = sr.ReadLine()))
        {


            index = line.IndexOf("=");


           //    value_of_each_key = line.Substring(index+1);



            if (index >= 1)
            {
                key_of_each_line = line.Substring(0, index);
                if (key_of_each_line == key)
                {
                    key_value = line.Substring(key.Length + 1);
                }

            }
            else
            {
            }


        }
        sr.Close();
        return key_value;
    }


/*----------------------------------------------------------
 * Function     : SetKey
 * Description  : sets a value to the specified key
 * Parameters   : key and a value
 * Return       : none
 * --------------------------------------------------------*/
    public void SetKey(string key , string value)
    {
        bool key_was_found_inside_the_loop;
        string value_of_each_key;
        string key_of_each_line ;
        string line;
        int index;
        key_was_found_inside_the_loop = false;

        temp_settings_file = "\\temp_settings_file.txt";
        temp_settings_dir = path_exe + @"\temp_settings";
        if (!Directory.Exists(temp_settings_dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(temp_settings_dir);
        }

        sw = new StreamWriter(temp_settings_dir+temp_settings_file);
        sr = new StreamReader(Options_File);
        while (null != (line = sr.ReadLine()))
        {

            index = line.IndexOf("=");
            key_of_each_line = line.Substring(0, index);
            value_of_each_key = line.Substring( index + 1);
         //   key_value = line.Substring(0,value.Length);
            if (key_of_each_line == key)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(key + " = " + value);
                key_was_found_inside_the_loop = true;

            }
            else
            {
                sw.WriteLine(key_of_each_line+"="+value_of_each_key);
            }

        }

        if (!key_was_found_inside_the_loop)
        {
           sw.WriteLine(key + "=" + value);
        }
        sr.Close();
        sw.Close();
        File.Delete(Options_File);
        File.Move(temp_settings_dir + temp_settings_file, Options_File);
        return;

    }
```

After this two functions i did:

```
public List<float> GetListFloatKey(string keys)
    {
        int j;
        List<float> t;
        t = new List<float>();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; ; i++)
        {
            j = Convert.ToInt32(GetKey((keys + i).ToString()));
            if (j == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                t.Add(j);
            }
        }
        if (t.Count == 0)
            return null;
        else
            return t;
    }

    public void SetListFloatKey(string key, List<float> Values)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < Values.Count; i++)
        {
            string indexed_key;
            indexed_key = string.Format("{0}{1}", key, i);
            //  indexed_key = Key + i.ToString();
            SetKey(indexed_key, Values[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```

But they are not good.

The last one the SetListFloatKey when i put a List in it the result in the text file settings_file.txt is for exmaple:

coordinates01 = 123

coordinates02 = 144

coordinates03 = 145

For every cell/index in the List i get its making a key. What i need is that the List i get will have one key the format in the text file should be like this:

coordinates = 123,144,145......and so on one key and then all the values from the List i get.

Then in the GetListFloatKey i need re format the values according to the key for example coordinates and return a List with the values in index 0 123 in 1 144 in 2 145 and so on....

The qustion if the function the way im doing them are good in the way im using in both GetKey and SetKey ? And how do i format and re format the values ?

Comment: Did you ever program in C# before? i would recommend you to check some guidelines ( http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/11/top-6-coding-standards-guideline.html )

Comment: using your current code you will have to re-write the entire options file for each float value you are assigning and for each key you set.  You should consider using something like the class I posted in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you are calling SetKey within SetListFloatKey for every item in the list. Instead, you need to build a string and call it once, along the lines of (basic testing done):

```
public static void SetListFloatKey(string key, List<float> Values)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (float value in Values)
  {
    sb.AppendFormat("{0},", value);
  }
  SetKey(key, sb.ToString());
}
```

Note I am getting lazy here - the last item will have a comma after it. Then when loading the list:

```
public static List<float> GetListFloatKey(string keys)
{
  List<float> result = new List<float>();
  string s = GetKey(keys);
  string[] items = s.Split(new char[] { ',' });
  float f;
  foreach (string item in items)
  {
    if (float.TryParse(item, out f))
      result.Add(f);
  }
  return result;
}
```

However, given you are reading and writing an options file, you might want to investigate options around serializing your objects to and from files.

**EDIT** There are a few ways you can get rid of the extra comma. One way is to not put it in in the first place...

```
  string sep = "";
  foreach (float value in Values)
  {
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", sep, value);
    if (sep == "") sep = ",";
  }
```

...and another is to exclude it in the call to SetKey...

```
  foreach (float value in Values)
  {
    sb.AppendFormat(",{0}", value);
  }
  SetKey(key, sb.ToString().Substring(1));
```

..note that in both of these cases I moved the comma to the start to make life easier. Alternatively, you could store the numbers in an array and use Array.Join.

Comment: Michael ok looks good. How can i remove the comma in the end ? Give me the explantion and i will do it i never used AppendFormat before.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are wasting too much time thinking about how to format the file each time you make a change, you are also causing a lot of file overhead each time you check for a key.

Consider using a class like

```
    public class Options
    {
        public static string FILENAME = @"C:\Test\testfile.txt";

        public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> OrderedKeys { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>> Pairs { get; set; }

        public string GetKey(string key)
        {
            return this.Pairs[key].Value;
        }

        public void SetKey(string key, string value)
        {
            if(this.Pairs.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, string> pair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);
                this.OrderedKeys.Insert(this.OrderedKeys.IndexOf(this.Pairs[key]), pair);
                this.Pairs[key] = pair;
            }
        }

        public Options()
        {
            LoadFile();
        }

        ~Options()
        {
            WriteFile();
        }

        private void LoadFile()
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<key>\S*?)\s*=\s*(?<val>\S*?)\s*\r\n");
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(FILENAME));

            this.OrderedKeys = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            this.Pairs = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, string> pair = 
                    new KeyValuePair<string,string>(match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["val"].Value);

                this.OrderedKeys.Add(pair);
                this.Pairs.Add(pair.Key, pair);
            }
        }

        private void WriteFile()
        {
            if (File.Exists(FILENAME))
                File.Delete(FILENAME);

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FILENAME))
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in this.OrderedKeys)
                {
                    file.WriteLine(pair.Key + " = " + pair.Value);
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Notice that the options object will read from the file once, and writeout when it is destroyed, meanwhile it will hold a local dictionary of the values in your file.  You can then GetKey() and SetKey() to get and set your options.

I modified my original post to use a list and a dictionary, this is because a Dictionary on its own does not maintain the original order that pairs are added, so the list ensures that the options are always written to the file in the correct order.

You will also notice I threw in a Regular Expression to parse your file, makes things much easier and quicker and allows for things like extra whitespace in the options file.

Once you have done this it is easy to add functions like

```
        public List<float> GetListFloatKey(string keybase)
        {
            List<float> ret = new List<float>();
            foreach (string key in this.Pairs.Keys)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(key, keybase + "[0-9]+"))
                    ret.Add(float.Parse(this.Pairs[key].Value));
            }

            return ret;
        }

        public void SetListFloatKey(string keybase, List<float> values)
        {
            List<string> oldkeys = new List<string>();
            int startindex = -1;
            foreach (string key in this.Pairs.Keys)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(key, keybase + "[0-9]+"))
                {
                    if (startindex == -1)
                        startindex = this.OrderedKeys.IndexOf(this.Pairs[key]);

                    oldkeys.Add(key);
                }
            }

            foreach (string key in oldkeys)
            {
                this.OrderedKeys.Remove(this.Pairs[key]);
                this.Pairs.Remove(key);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, string> pair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keybase + i.ToString(), values[i].ToString());
                if (startindex != -1)
                    this.OrderedKeys.Insert(startindex + i, pair);
                else
                    this.OrderedKeys.Add(pair);

                this.Pairs.Add(pair.Key, pair);
            }
        }
```

It is easier to do that at this point because you have abstracted the actual file structure away and are now just dealing with a Dictionary

Comment: Jimmy i will try it as well. Thanks.